# How to define a Global variable in python?

Tags: python

I am newbee in Python . JUst wandering if it is possible to define a Global variable in Python.

I have this python code to compute total number of times Fib(2) has been accessed. But count is printing 0 when called.

```
import sys



def fib(n):
    """Takes input a natural number n > 0.
        Returns n! """

    global count
    count = 0
    if n == 1 or n == 0:
        return 1

    else:
        if n == 2:
            print 'encountered here::: '
            count += 1
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)

def main():
    x = int(raw_input('Enter a natural number > 0 :'))
    print 'Fibonacci(%d) = %d' % (x, fib(x))
    print 'Count =', count
if 1:
    main()
```

Comment: Put `global count` inside the `fib` function.

Comment: I did. But when I want to print count from main after calling say fib(4) its printing 0.

Comment: Put `count = 0` in module scope (after the import, for example). Be sure to keep the `global count` in `fib`.

Comment: As a beginner, you are probably better off assuming you cannot declare global variables, as this will help you avoid using them unnecessarily.

Comment: As chepner mentioned. Don't use global variables please. They can lead to unreadable code and are generally regarded as a bad habit.

Comment: Global variables are only global to a module. Just **don't** use them if you are a beginner.

Comment: So suppose you want to know how many times fib function has been accessed? how would you you do it without using a global variable or returning touple.

Answer (score 3):

A variable defined in the module outside of any function is considered a `global variable`.  To modify a `global variable` inside of a function, you must write `global variableName` inside of the function.

You did this, however, that variable is **only** defined in your function, it must also be declared outside of the function to be considered a global variable.  If not, it will be local to your function, despite the `global` in front of it.

TL;DR Also declare the variable outside of your function.

## EDIT (I was wrong):

By writing `global variableName` in a function **and** executing said function, it **does** make the variable a `global variable`; if not you would be getting a `NameError` when you tried to print it.

The reason that you're getting a 0, however, is because everytime you call your function, you initialize `count` to 0.  Nonetheless, the solution about still holds.

Answer (score 2):

Move `count = 0` outside your `fib(n)` function. You only need to declare it as `global count` once inside the function, while the initialization should be outside. What you're doing is that you are re-initializing it with 0 every time the function is called.

```
import sys

count = 0

def fib(n):
    """Takes input a natural number n > 0.
        Returns n! """

    global count
    if n == 1 or n == 0:
        return 1

    else:
        if n == 2:
            print 'encountered here::: '
            count += 1
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)

def main():
    x = int(raw_input('Enter a natural number > 0 :'))
    print 'Fibonacci(%d) = %d' % (x, fib(x))
    print 'Count =', count
if 1:
    main()
```

Although, you should avoid global variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
global foo
foo = [1,2,3]
```

Now `foo` can be used anywhere in the program

Answer (score 0):

Put the count = 0 outside the function.